# Extjs adding a idproperty to fields defined in a store

Tags: extjs

I'm setting my fields directly in the store configuration.

```
Ext.define('T.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    autoLoad: false,

    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to set somehow an idProperty for these fields direct in the store ? The only option I see is to create a separate model class containing a idProperty. But I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can theoretically change the `idProperty` from within the constructor this way:

```
Ext.define('T.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    autoLoad: false,

    constructor: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.model.prototype.idProperty = 'Id';
    },

    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work for implicit models (at least since I last tested it) and in that case the user need to define the model and the `idProperty` himself.

Comment: Yeah, then that issue is fixed by know. +1

Comment: Your solution has indirectly solved an different issue to which I was facing : the `idProperty` that I had defined in the reader's config was ignored (ExtJS 4.1.3). My store is not so far from the one described by Sra, except that I don't define the model by myself and my `idProperty` is set to `"value"`.

Comment: I copied this example and used it in Sencha Touch 2.3 and get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Answer (score 14):

The default id Property is `id`. You can change it either on the model or the reader of the proxy.

***Note:** the store can use the proxy of the model (not done in this example).*

Example (with both)

```
// Set up a model to use in our Store
 Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     idProperty: 'Id',
     fields: [
         {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age',       type: 'int'},
         {name: 'eyeColor',  type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

 var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/users.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users',
             idProperty: 'Id'
         }
     },
     autoLoad: true
 });
```

Comment: `s/idPoperty/idProperty/` (lower one, too few chars to edit myself.)

Comment: @msanford Pardon, what do you mean should be fixed?

Comment: There's a typo in the store's reader definition, `idPoperty` (missing r) :)

Comment: Insufficient rep to make arbitrary one-char edits. Just thought I'd mention it. :)

Answer (score 3):

For ExtJS 6

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.data.ProxyStore',

    /**
     * @cfg {String} idProperty
     */
    // idProperty: null,

    privates: {
        createImplicitModel: function(fields) {
            var me = this,
                modelCfg = {
                    extend: me.implicitModel,
                    statics: {
                        defaultProxy: 'memory'
                    }
                },
                proxy, model;
            if (fields) {
                modelCfg.fields = fields;
            }
            // add
            if(me.idProperty) {
                modelCfg.idProperty = me.idProperty;
            }

            model = Ext.define(null, modelCfg);
            me.setModel(model);
            proxy = me.getProxy();
            if (proxy) {
                model.setProxy(proxy);
            } else {
                me.setProxy(model.getProxy());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Example

```
Ext.define('T.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    autoLoad: false,
    idProperty: 'Id',

    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

Test

```
var store = Ext.create('T.store.Users');
console.log(store.model.idProperty); // "Id"
console.log(store.model.idField); // constructor {name: "Id", type: "int"..}
store.add({Id: '11', Name: 'XXX'})
```

Comment: you make my day. I confirm your override works fine with ExtJS 6.6 CE (modern toolkit).